# How to set background color with jQuery CSS selector

Tags: jquery, css

I'm using jQuery and JavaScript to loop through the `<td>`s in a `<table>` and count the `<TD>`s which have the background color of 'Yellow' but the problem is it isn't working and I really am not sure how.

I first thought it was because I was using background-color rather than backgroundColor in the if statement

```
if ($("td").css("background-color") == "yellow") {
```

but after interchanging both of them it still doesn't work. I'm using a `.each()` function to get all the `<td>`. The `.each()` function does work as it is counting 42 `<td>`s which is correct, but when I implement the CSS checker it doesn't work (No errors are reported).

```
 $.ajax({
    url: "api/submit-red.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: $(".submit-move").serialize(),
    success: function(result){
        $("td").each(function() {
            if ($("td").css("backgroundColor") == "yellow") {
                console.log("working");
            }
        });
       }
 });
```

The console is not prompting "Working" even though there is a `td` with the background color 'yellow'

========

The answer was a combination between them all. Rather than correct the code above I will explain the errors down here.

- I needed to use `$(this)` rather than `$("td")` in the if statement to cycle through the different `<td>`
- I needed to use RGB rather than the color name `yellow` which **requires** the whitespace
- I needed to use `background-color` over `backgroundColor` as the css property

Comment: JavaScript is case sensitive.

Comment: so your request may be failed instead of getting success result.

Comment: first try: `success: function(result){ console.log('working');}`

Comment: @BhojendraNepal I wrote in the post about the each function working which is inside the success function. I'm certain of the success working.

Comment: I think you haven't defined background-color for td???

Comment: Use `"rgb(255, 255, 255)"` to check the condition, you'll get exact results. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two issue in your code:

1) Use current context `this` to target current element in each context.

2) You will get the returned color in rgb format. you need to convert it to name for comparison. or compare with rgb value

```
$("td").each(function() {
   if ($(this).css("backgroundColor") == "rgb(255, 255, 0)") {
      console.log("working");
   }
});
```

Comment: The answer was really a combination between them all. I will go with this one.
I have to use `background-color` over `backgroundColor` and because of the comment from Michael It worked. Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("td").each(function() {
     if ($(this).css("background-color") == "yellow") {
         console.log("working");
       }
   });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because if you do your check the real value of `$('div').css('backgroundColor')` is not "yellow" but `rgb(255, 255, 0)` The result seems to be send as a RGB value.